# NetCore project - Nuget configuration is invalid

Tags: configuration, nuget

I have an old porject i need to work on, and suddenly, got this message.

[error shown by VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3v5h.png)

I've tried to closing and then re-opening VS to see if it helps, it didn't. Then created a new project and try to manage nuget packages, but i get the same error. There was no Nuget.Config file, no nothing, just a NEW project and the VS error message persists... 
So, what would be a real solution for this scenario?
Because I've seen some answers indicating that reopening VS solved the problem, others said that removing Nuget.config file, but nothing solves this. 
Right now I am only able to run some projects where i don't need to redownload dependencies, but for new or old projects which haven't used Nuget yet, I am not able to build anything.

I am currently running with:
[specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIIaE.png)

**UPDATE:**

After trying this steps I managed to solved the problem

- Go to this path: C:\Users{{username}}\AppData\Roaming.
- Delete Nuget.config.
- Restart your machine. Restarting Vs did not solved the problem, but
  restarting my machine did.

So the error was an actual "NuGet.config" setting hosted outside my solution/project.

Comment: I had exact;y the same problem running the latest version o VS2019. Followed your advice and now it works again - thanks